# How can we add background music in swift playground?(using AVFoundation)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Through music is playing perfectly but I am not able to execute my main programme.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

print("Hello, Audio!") 

if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drum01", withExtension: "mp3") {
    do {
        let midi = try AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: url, soundBankURL: nil)
        midi.play(nil)
        while midi.isPlaying {
            // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        print("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @AhmadF it does not works in playground it only works in terminal

Comment: Easy, you can't.  The linked duplicate mentions that.

Comment: @JAL code of duplicate works only in terminal

Comment: @JAL     #!/usr/bin/swift

import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

var error: NSError?

println("Hello, Audio!")
var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/somebody/myfile.mid") // Change to a local midi file
var midi = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, soundBankURL: nil, error: &error)
if midi == nil {
    if let e = error {
        println("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
midi.play(nil)
while midi.playing {
    // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
} **It does not works in playground !**

Comment: @EricAya Presently now i have come down with this code :                          import UIKit
import AVFoundation

print("Hello, Audio!")
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drum01", withExtension: "mp3") {
    do {
        let midi = try AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: url, soundBankURL: nil)
        midi.play(nil)
        while midi.isPlaying {
            // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        print("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

Comment: @EricAya the only problem i am facing with this code is that the music is working perfectly but main programme is not executing

Comment: @EricAya Can you please explain how this code can be written with the same functionality without Do-While loop?

Comment: @EricAya main content means apart from the background music other contents of my programme e.g display etc . Secondly I was doing this with my own code instead of using a library. Could you please give me a hint about how to do this please? :)

Answer (score -2):

do you add "mySound" to your project?
And what type of "mySound" ->  `ofType: "mySound"`
sample: `ofType: "mp3"`

Comment: He's talking about a Swift playground, not a project.